# Terminal/Shell config Question

Tags: bash, shortcuts, history

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- TERM=wyse60
- SHELL=`/bin/bash`
- `set -o vi`
- telnet using TinyTerm v4.20.1306 with wyse60 emulation

**My question is:**
Is there something I can add to `.bash_profile` to allow `.bash_history` to work properly with the up and down arrow keys?

The <kbd>up arrow</kbd> key currently exports a `^K` ...
bash expects an <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for bash history (Next).

The <kbd>down arrow</kbd> key currently appears to be exporting a `^J`...
bash expects an <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for bash history (Previous).

Comment: Since you're using `set -o vi` have you tried entering insert mode with `i` key and then press arrow up ?

Comment: at the bash prompt $, typing i up arrow results in $ i^K ... clearly bash is not interpreting the vi insert mode ... I can type ESC K or ESC J but defeats the simplicity I had in 14.04 with just typing the arrow keys